# How do you create a link from data retrieved from the database

Tags: php

I have products stored in a database. These items have ID, NAME, QUANTITY, and STOCK_NUMBER fields. I want to make an `href` for all of the data in the database:

```
$Result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Products");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($Result)){ 

href .....


}
```

I want the result like this

`item_id=1&name_1_tv&quantity_1=2&stock_number_1=1411
&item_id=2&name_2_mobile&quantity_2=5&stock_number_2=5894
&item_id=3&name_3_radio&quantity_3=2&stock_number_3=18541
&item_id=4&name_4_tv&quantity_4=2&stock_number_4=1025
&item_id=5&name_5_computer&quantity_5=1&stock_number_5=1455
&item_id=6&name_6_cd&quantity_6=2&stock_number_6=5888`

all these under the link

Comment: If the database is too big, the URL will become too long. You propably want do do it using POST. Uh, and why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: And why did you write your first sentence in capital letters?

Comment: CHECK YOUR KEYBOARD, YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY SEEMS TO BE STUCK!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($Result)) // note the change to assoc
 { 
     $query = http_build_query($row);
     echo "&$query<br>";
 }
```

Note that GET requests have very low maximum length limits. IE chokes on URLs longer than 2 kilobytes, for example.

Comment: I think that he wants it to be one big string - maybe you should echo "&$query" or "$query" if in the first row?

Comment: @thejh true. I changed it a bit to form a big block, the OP'll have to do the details